# Is mysql_real_escape_string really necessary in insert or update query other than a select query?

Tags: php, mysql

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is used as a security measure to prevent MySQL injection, while data is fetched from the database. But is it really necessary in case of insert or update statements? If so why?

Comment: Of course you have the escape for inserts/updates.... do you think that a name field containing "John O'Brien" doesn't need escaping to handle the `'` if it's used in an insert/update?.... Of course, if you were living in the 21st century, you'd be using prepared statements/bind variables anyway, and this question would be an irrelevance

Comment: It isn't the perfect security solution. Moreover, MySQL extension is deprecated. Use prepared statements instead with MySQLi or PDO. Regarding answer for your question, security inputs should be sanitized whenever you are querying or updating database based on user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of mysql_real_escape_string() is flawed.

Any time you are inserting user input into a SQL query you need to escape the string. So, yes you would absolutely escape when running insert and update statement.

An SQL injection attack (which mysql_real_escape_string() can help prevent) is performed when an attacking party inserts SQL queries into a registration form for example.
The strings from the registration form will likely by inserted into the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, insert and update queries are equally vulnerable for SQL injections.
It is advisable to use PDO though.